# Symfony2 url hierarchical structure

Tags: url, symfony, routes, hierarchy, router

I was wondering whats the best approach to have a hierarchical structured urls such as for example:

If i have 3 categories

```
-Cateogory1
--Category2
---Category3
```

I would like the urls to resolve to

```
/category1
/category1/category2
/category1/category2/category3
```

I am also using `jms_i18n_routes` to support locales in the routes. I have the `SymfonyExtraBundle` already enabled. The only way i see for now is just to create a new router and add it to the list of routers but the problem is the `jms_i18_router` extends the symfony default router so if i do that i will be able to have internationalized urls for all the default routes but not for this custom router, which means i will have to copy the functionality which i already have into the new router (pretty pointless)

Furthermore if I add this router for a category hierarchy, I will probably have to have different versions of it for different entity types in addition to categories where i want this functionality (or have one giant if statement to check for each scenario) - neither solution seems very elegant to me, so I was wondering what are your thoughts on the matter?
Thanks!

Comment: That might be one possible solition: http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/01/symfony2-dynamically-add-routes/ the problem with it is how do we clear ONLY the routes cache so that its updated only when we update a category slug for instance so that the link is correct...

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by setting rout repetitive pattern, use regular expression on the "requirements" part of rout, similar this:

```
# categories rout:
categories:  
    pattern:       /{cat}  
    defaults:      { _controller: HelloBundle:Default:categories }  
    requirements:
        cat:       (category[1-9]\/)+
```

### notice:

#### you should recognize slashes on $cat variable on the "categoriesAction" function.

of course if you want make dynamic hierarchical URL from non-ascii characters and make this URL from persisted entities i think you can do this by create URL from a ascii entity field such as entity-id or other entity-special-keys.